# openssl unable to get local issuer certificate debian

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I can not verify the certificate by openssl

```
openssl verify cert.pem
```

Gets something like this:

> cert.pem: / C = PL / O = DATA
>   error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate

The same cert from the machine on Centos - verified correctly.

Debian: squeeze / sid

Is it a problem with the CA ROOT? Update openssl help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 12):

Unlike browsers, which trust nearly everything from anybody, OpenSSL trusts nothing by default.

Its up to you to determine what should be trusted. You will have to specify something when using OpenSSL. It may be a cert or list of certs to trust.

The directory `/etc/ssl/certs` contains many certs. Using such directory should allow to verify almost anything:

```
openssl verify -CApath /etc/ssl/certs cert.pem
```

It is recommended that you reduce the number of trusted certs to one, two or the minimum possible.

Comment: Still coudn't get mine to work (letsencrypt) : `root@messagerie-secours[CHROOT][10.10.10.19] /etc/ssl/private/LETSENCRYPT # openssl verify -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt chained_cert.crt 
chained_cert.crt: CN = messagerie.algerian-radio.dz
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
root@messagerie-secours[CHROOT][10.10.10.19] /etc/ssl/private/LETSENCRYPT # `

Comment: Browsers do not trust "everything from anybody", and OpenSSL has the same approach as browsers.  They both use an OS-provided or own list of trusted CAs.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the CA cert in order to verify the issued cert since it's obviously not included in the pem (though this would be possible):

```
openssl verify -CAfile your_ca_cert_file cert.pem
```

If you do not get the error on centOS then there's the CA cert around and openssl can use it to successfully verify cert.pem

Comment: Thx for replay.

If I understood: - From the Debian done command: openssl verify -CAfile ca-bundle.crt cert.pem where: - Ca-bundle.crt - ROOT CA of the certificate issuer (Unizeto / Certum - Poland) - Cert.pem - certificate obtained from the issuer (Unizeto / Certum - Poland)

The result - test performed on a Debian system:

openssl verify -CAfile bundle.crt ca-cert.pem cert.pem: OK

openssl verify cert.pem cert.pem: / C = PL / O = data... error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate

How to do that without indicating ca-bundle.crt - my certificate has a status of OK?

Comment: You can also set and export the environment variables SSL_CERT_FILE or SSL_CERT_DIR... `export SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/ca_bundle.crt` or `export SSL_CERT_DIR=/path/to/ca/dir` Then you do not have to specify CAfile or CApath in every openssl command.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your CA trusted on the server. For example, if your cert is from goadday, run the following commands.

```
cd /tmp
sudo wget -O gd_intermediate.crt https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_intermediate.crt
sudo cp /tmp/gd_intermediate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/gd_intermediate.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

After running these commands, your certificate should be verified.

```
openssl verify cert.pem
```

Comment: You should not use wget to download certificates. There are known weaknesses with wget. A viable alternative is curl. I'm too lazy to provide a link though.